# Use updated req variable in middleware after route execution

Tags: express

I have a middleware function I wrote to perform some logging for each HTTP request that comes in

```
export const winstonMiddlewareLogger = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    let _startTime = new Date();
    res.on("finish", function() {
        let responseTime = new Date().getTime() - _startTime.getTime() + "ms";
        let method = req.method;
        let url = req.originalUrl;
        let body = req.body ? req.body : {};
        let query = req.query;
        let params = req.params;
        let status = res.statusCode;
        let msg = `HTTP ${req.method} ${req.url} ${responseTime}`;
        let logDocument = {
            msg,
            method,
            url,
            params,
            query,
            body,
            status,
            responseTime,
        };
        logger.info(undefined, logDocument)
    });
    next();
};
```

Next thing I have a route

```
app.post("/slow", (req, res) => {
    req.testParam = "test";
    res.send("hello");
});
```

I want to be able to access the new property of the `req` parameter that is initiated in the `/slow` (`testParam`), in the `res.on(...){...}` event listener in my middleware function the next way:

```
if (req.hasOwnProperty('testParam')) {
       console.log(req.testParam)
   }
```

But the current state is that the `req` parameter is not updated no matter what I do in the route itself, because the `req` parameter it knows is only the one I get at the beginning of each request.
Changing the `req` variable in the route doesn't change it in the middleware which has already got a `req` variable of its own.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found [winston-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-winston) which actually does the things I wanted to.
What it does is to reassign the `res.end` function to a function he wrote himself.
This function can access the modified objects of `req` and `res` after the route has already executed.

So for the sake of showing how it works, I change my route to:

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    req._attributeFromRoute = "test";
    res.send("hello");
});
```

And my middleware function looks something like this:

```
export const winstonMiddlewareLogger2 = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
    let _startTime = new Date();
    let end = res.end;
    res.end = (chunk: any, encoding: string, cb?: () => void): void => {
        res.end = end;
        res.end(chunk, encoding, cb);

        console.log(req._attributeFromRoute)  // Notice that this property was not declared before the route execution, and now we can access it after it was defined

        let responseTime = new Date().getTime() - _startTime.getTime() + "ms";
        let method = req.method;
        let url = req.originalUrl;
        let body = req.body ? req.body : {};
        let query = req.query;
        let params = req.params;
        let status = res.statusCode;
        let msg = `HTTP ${req.method} ${req.url} ${responseTime}`;
        let logDocument = {
            msg,
            method,
            url,
            params,
            query,
            body,
            status,
            responseTime,
        };
        logger.info(undefined, logDocument)
    };
    next();
};
```

And the way it will work is that the middleware function will wait for the route to execute and call the `req.end` function, which will enter the `end` function we created ourselfs.
We will then execute the original `end` function that had as a reference in the `end` variable.
Then we can do whatever we want with the updated objects of `req` and `res`.